# Alternative to "Merry Christmas"

Tags: phrases, greetings, christmas

The common greeting for the new year is

> I wish you a merry Christmas and a happy new year.

Since Christmas has religious roots, it may not be suitable for people who are not religious. Shortening the greeting to

> I wish you a happy new year

seems lame. What's a charming alternative?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holiday_greetings

Comment: I don't like to sound like a grumpy old git, but I've long thought these xmas card messages are a bit misplaced. Rates for suicide, murder, wounding, etc., shoot up over xmas - partly because a lot more booze gets consumed, but partly because when families are crammed together for a few days, things often get *fractious* rather than *happy*.

Comment: +1 for looking at the issue from a quite different angle ;)

Comment: Sounds like the solution is to banish alcohol and abolish all *happy* "family get togethers". Then the world would be at peace year-round ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  So you're thinking something more along the lines of a fractious Festivus?

Comment: @Blrfl: Well, my nan actually pegged out at 99, but I know she wasn't keen on the possibility of having a big gathering if she'd made one more year. I just think all the commercialisation/conventionality surrounding big-time festivities can eventually end up being counter-productive. And I've never even had to *do* all the cooking & stuff - I'm sure loads of people really sigh when they realise it's time to spend another whole week in the kitchen, while the rest of the family alternate between stuffing their faces and arguing.

Comment: FWIW, I am fairly anti-Christian but I don't mind Christmas. After all, it's a non-Christian tradition that's been "Christianized" so in a way I think it's funny to see Christians celebrating it.

Comment: Christmas Day is a Federal Holiday.  That is it's name.  I'm adding this as a comment because it's appropriate to call it by it's name, regardless of the religious context.  For example, were there a Cult of the Halloween, you wouldn't try to skirt around saying Halloween at the end of October.  "Happy Scary Candy Day!"

Comment: @Kalamane I think you could call Halloween "All Saint's Day Eve".

Comment: I'm with @Kalamane. I certainly wouldn't be offended if someone wished me a Happy Chanukah even though I'm not Jewish. We just need to get over the walking on egg-shells PC thing when it comes to holidays.

Comment: A once-common greeting in parts of U.S.—appropriate only on Christmas day—was "Christmas gift!" See http://dare.wisc.edu/?q=node/73. William Dean Howells, _A Boy's Town_ (1890), describes how the greeting was used in the 1800s: "The first thing when you woke you tried to catch everybody, and you caught a person if you said "Christmas Gift!" before he or she did; and the person you caught had to give you a present. Nobody said "Merry Christmas!" as people do now, and I do not know where the custom of saying 'Christmas Gift' came from. It seems more sordid and greedy than it really was..."

Answer (score 37):

It is common in the US to use "Season's Greetings" or "Happy Holidays" as a more secular sentiment for this time of year ([Wikipedia has a pretty good description of these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holiday_greetings)). Also, "Happy New Year" by itself is quite common and not considered lame at all.

Finally, I am not Christian, but I don't find it offensive when well-wishers offer me a "Merry Christmas." I take it in the spirit it is intended. I offer them a "Happy Solstice" or a "Good Yule" in return (or occasionally a "Happy Festivus").

Comment: +1 Though in my experience, no one actually *says* "season's greetings." You just see it on holiday cards. "Happy holidays" is quite standard.

Comment: Or 'Have a cool Yule'.

Comment: The way I look at it is that if a Jewish friend offered Happy Channukah to me, and I were offended at that, wouldn't that make me a jerk? Wouldn't it make me a jerk to be offended if he said that IN RETURN to my "Merry Christmas"? Can't we, if you'll pardon the expression, just all get along?

Comment: Christmas is one of many winter festivals. It has pre-Christian roots but has a Christian name and story. It is the dominant cultural festival in the UK, and is socially important and transcends the religion. But I'm an atheist so I would say that.

Comment: I like the first sentence of your last paragraph, but "happy solstice" or "good yule"?? If you're not offended to be wished a merry Christmas, why not just offer the same in return? Arguably the majority of the world celebrates Christmas, or at least the majority of the US (if that's where you happen to be).

Comment: @Daniel Oh certainly, one could offer a Merry Christmas in return. I don't personally, but I didn't mean to exclude this as a possibility.

Comment: I use "Season's Greetings" all year round.

Comment: “Happy Holidays <...open card> is what terrorists say.  Merry Christmas, Avery and Jack.”

Comment: A well-used Seinfeld reference gets you an easy +1

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens: Why would you say "Merry Christmas" to someone who you know doesn't celebrate it? Yes, it would make you an extra jerk (and possibly a psychopath) if he replied "Happy Hanukkah" and you got offended, but even the initial overture is a bit jerkish.

Comment: Well, it's just one of those things that I think has fallen by the wayside. When I was growing up in rural PA in the 70's, I had a lot of Jewish friends, and it was all one big happy town. Saying "Happy Hanukkah" and replying "And a merry Christmas to you" was de rigeur, and all in good cheer. Saying "Happy Hannukah" to someone who knew you weren't Jewish would have been odd. Of course, where we've ended up now is that nobody says anything, except as a pro forma "Happy Holidays. Your total will be $16.49."

Answer (score 12):

This is a social propriety question and not a language question. But in that spirit, here's my answer:

If you're a non-Christian and don't celebrate Christmas, or if the person you're speaking to does not celebrate Christmas, then just say "hello"! Why in the world do people look for a way to bring up a specific religious holiday without mentioning the holiday?

As a Christian, I find it highly offensive when people say, "Happy Holiday Season" or the like. What holiday is it that you are referring to? So why can't you say "Merry Christmas"? Do you hate Christians so much that you can't even bring yourself to SAY THE NAME of our holiday?

I have no problem saying "Happy Hannukah" to Jewish friends. I once sent a Chinese friend an e-card for Tet. I'd be happy to give Ramadan greetings to a Moslem friend if I knew the appropriate greeting. ("Happy Ramadan" seems inappropriate for what is a pretty somber holiday, but I don't know.)

I often hear people say that "Happy Holidays" is "more inclusive". This is simply absurd. The whole point of saying "Happy Holidays" is to refuse to acknowledge Christmas. That is, the whole point is to EXCLUDE a specific group.

Suppose that a store put out an ad on Martin Luther King Day that said "Mid-January Holiday Sale" and which pictured only white people. When asked, they explained that they didn't want to refer to it as Martin Luther King Day or to include pictures of black people because they were afraid that that might offend Nazis and Klansmen. Would you say that that store was being "inclusive", and praise them for their tolerance in avoiding such offense? Or would you say that they were pandering to racists and bigots?

Likewise, I think most non-Christians understand that Christians celebrate this holiday called "Christmas", and while they do not celebrate it themselves, they don't begrudge others having their own holidays. To say that someone else should not be "allowed" to have a holiday that you do not celebrate, or to go out of your way to pretend this holiday doesn't exist, is simply rude and intolerant.

If you want to wish someone a merry Christmas, say "Merry Christmas". If you don't want to acknowledge Christmas, than just say "Hi, Bob!" or "Wow, cold weather we're having, isn't it?" But bringing up someone else's holiday and then making a pointed effort to not acknowledge it is just insulting.

</rant>

Comment: There are multiple reasons that people say "Happy Holidays". One of those reasons is to be as non-offensive as possible (a lighter version of your "refuse to acknowledge Christmas"). However, there are plenty of other reasons. To assume that you know the reason that the person greeting you is saying "Happy Holidays" is to be presumptuous. To take offense at it is to have a very thin skin, the very thing that many defenders of "Merry Christmas" say about those who get offended by that phrase. Personally, I find either phrase perfectly adequate.

Comment: This entire rant is based on the faulty assumption that you either "acknowledge" Christmas or you are refusing to acknowledge Christmas. Christmas is not the center of everyone's life. Similarly, Canadians are not "refusing to acknowledge Independence Day" in the beginning of July, nor are they "EXCLUDING" Americans. The point of saying "Happy Holidays" is to wish someone happiness during a time of many holidays without making religious assumptions, no more and no less.

Comment: @BenHocking: While it's not offensive in the least for someone to respond with "happy holidays" (i.e., [holy days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holiday#Etymology)), in the US you would have to be living under a rock to be unaware that secularists have been trying to de-Christianize Christmas for a long time. Jay's answer is a reasonable response to this nonsense.

Comment: @Daniel: In the US, you _would_ have to be living under a rock not to be aware that many people _think_ that secularists have been trying to de-Christanize Christmas for a long time. I personally think it's much more complicated than that (e.g., was the introduction of Santa the beginning of this process?), but more importantly, by making such an assumption, you basically end up with a "Bah, humbug" _squared_. Please, let's just take greetings at face value and not look for reasons to be offended. Otherwise, I risk offending some people by saying "Merry Christmas" and others by not.

Comment: There are some factual items in this answer, and advice for usage, but it is marred by opinionating and social judgment. Can you remove the ranting part and leave in the factual, language part?

Comment: There are two logically combined reasons for referring to 'Holidays' rather than 'Christmas'. 1) It is hard to tell by looking at someone what holidays they celebrate or care about, and 2) there are a number of non-trivial subpopulations that celebrate non-Christmas holidays at the same time as Christmas. Re your rant, presumably some people are wishing you well for New Years, too, without having to say the extra long greeting, not trying to exclude Christmas but to include New Years?

Comment: Once, I said "Happy Holidays" to a co-worker. He replied, "Don't you mean 'Merry Christmas'?" I said, "I thought you had vacation next week and I wouldn't see you until after the new year." "Yeah?" "So, Happy Holidays: Christmas and New Years."

Comment: -1 it's not excluding Christmas it's including the other holidays that occur around that time Hannukah, Kwanzaa, etc.

Comment: @Yamikuronue: As I said in my post, I have no problem with someone not bringing up Christmas if they don't celebrate it. If you don't like Christmas, fine, just say "Hello". My problem is when they use a fake greeting like "Happy Holidays", which is clearly a deliberate effort to NOT acknowledge Christmas. Don't you see the difference?

Comment: @Hocking: You say that it is "thin-skinned" to be offended by "Happy Holidsays". But then you say that one should use this greeting to be "non-offensive". Non-offensive to whom? I presume you mean people who are offended just to hear the name of a holiday that they do not celebrate. How bigoted can someone be?! I am not offended to hear someone mention Hanukkah or Ramadan. That's because I'm not an intolerant bigot. If someone is offended just to be reminded that people of religions other than his own exist, he is by definition a bigot.

Comment: @Hocking: In your first post, you say that we should avoid mentioning Christmas to avoid offending non-Christians. In your second post, you say that it is a myth that anyone is trying to de-Christianize Christmas.

Comment: "Otherwise, I risk offending some people by saying "Merry Christmas" and others by not." Well, yes, that would be true. Given that there are Christians out there, and there are also intolerant anti-Christian bigots, then if you bring the subject up you will offend someone. Just like, if your audience includes some African-Americans and some Klansmen, anything you say about race will offend one group or the other.

Comment: @Mitch: How about, "Happy New Year"?

Comment: @Brown: Not mentioning Christmas is "not excluding Christmas"? So if on Martin Luther King Day I said, "Happy Mid-January Holiday!", would that be "not excluding MLK Day"?

Comment: @Brown: Well, of course the whole point of Kwanzaa is to "exclude Christmas", it's no coincidence that it comes on Dec 26. The man who invented Kwanzaa, Ron Karenga, wrote in his 1977 book "Kwanzaa: Origin, Concepts, Practice" that Kwanzaa "... was chosen to give a Black alternative to the existing holiday and give Blacks an opportunity to celebrate themselves and history, rather than simply imitate the practice of the dominant society." But hey, if I discover that someone I meet celebrates Kwanzaa, I'll gladly wish him a Happy Kwanzaa.

Comment: @Jay Happy Holidays is an effort to INCLUDE any holiday you may celebrate. By that token, "Merry Christmas" ought to be offensive to Jews because it's deliberately trying NOT to mention Hanukkah. Lolwut? How bigoted can you be, to assume that anyone trying to be inclusive is secretly just trying to piss you off by ignoring your holiday?

Comment: @Jay: You appear to be taking this very personally. Re-read what I wrote. You seem to be reading it _very_ selectively. I never said what you think I said, specifically "that one should use this greeting to be 'non-offensive'". What I said is that one reason people _do_ use it (not that they _should_) is because there are people on both sides of the issue who are sensitive. FWIW, if I knew you personally, I _would_ wish you a Merry Christmas, because I have no desire to offend _anyone_.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for a greeting message for the new year, what's wrong with "Happy New Year?" I don't see anything lame about it. Anyway…

#### Happy Holidays, Season's Greetings

If you're reasonably certain the person you are addressing lives in a region where these holidays are widely celebrated, you can say "Happy Holidays" or "Season's Greetings." That doesn't necessarily imply they *observe* those holidays religiously. It's just a euphonic way to point out a region of time and wishing them well. It would be like saying "have a nice weekend," even if they work on those days.

Comment: Personally, I wish folks a Happy Hogswatch.

Comment: "Happy Ick" @John ;)

Answer (score 5):

Happy non-denomination winter solstice period.

Comment: Except that I feel all excluded because Christmas for me happens just after the summer solstice. How about "Happy non-demoninational winter or summer solstice period"? Just rolls off the tongue.

Answer (score 3):

My personal favorite is:

> Happy Christmahanukwanzakkus

Comment: +1 for 'political correctness'! :) (whatever that may be...)

Answer (score 1):

Happy festivus and a Seinfeld new year!

Comment: Did you get your Festivus pole?

Comment: feats of strength,anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the origin of the holiday is the pagan holiday "Yule", also known as "Dude, it's the winter solstice, let's get drunk."[citation needed]; so you could say "A joyous Yule to you.".

Of course, it might be seen as insensitive by some, but a very good option seems to be the phrase "Merry Christmas, and a happy New Year.". This is a fairly good phrase to use if you want to:

1. Make it clear that you believe in Jesus Christ
2. Inform the listener that you wish them good cheer throughout the dark month of December.
3. You wish them good cheer through their New Year celebration.

Comment: The "Yule" might be religiously correct, but not geographically for those below the equator. It's summertime down here.