# New word for Christmas?

Tags: single-word-requests

Not that I'm pro/for 'christ out of christmas' but are schoolars thinking about a new word?

I mean this past 2013 Christmas season in Los Angeles I didn't see much of that word.

[update] chat about xmas
joe: I'm so excited happy holidays is coming!
jane: what? happy holidays?
joe: Yes! happy holidays is the best time of the year. I wish you a happy holidays!
jane: you are wierd!

Comment: Could you clarify why a part of a word should be removed or replaced, and why scholars should be thinking about that?

Comment: Don't know what schoolars are thinking, but are you after an alternative  definition for 'Christmas?

Comment: happy holidays does not cut it for me. Any alternative word for Christmas.

Comment: I am annoyed by your incongruent use of English grammar.

Comment: There's probably no more need to take the 'Christ' out of 'Christmas' than there is to take the 'holy' out of 'holiday'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to "Merry Christmas"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50673/alternative-to-merry-christmas)

Comment: But no one in Califormia would know what Christmas was if it bit them on the bum! An American I knew, when he experienced Christmas in the UK said it was 'like Christmas, Thanksgiving, 4th July, and George Washington's birthday all rolled into one'. It is massive and for many people involves at least a week's holiday. The festival itself was originally a pagan solstice celebration, and predates Christianity's arrival in Britain by many     centuries. But it remains 'Christmas' even in the UK's secular society. THREE CHEERS FOR CHRISTMAS.

Comment: Why should "Are scholars thinking about xyz" be an "opinion based" topic? Either they are thinking of it or not. You cannot really have "opinions" on that. You can have observations, and the OP was asking for such.

Answer (score 2):

One acquiring a following these days is [*Festivus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festivus):

> *Festivus*, a well-celebrated parody, has become a secular holiday celebrated on December 23 that serves as an alternative to participating in the pressures and commercialism of the Christmas season. Originally a family tradition of scriptwriter Dan O'Keefe, who worked on the American sitcom *Seinfeld*, the holiday entered popular culture after it was made the focus of a 1997 episode of the program. The holiday's celebration, as it was shown on *Seinfeld*, includes a *Festivus* dinner, an unadorned aluminum Festivus pole, practices such as the "Airing of Grievances" and "Feats of Strength," and the labeling of easily explainable events as "*Festivus* miracles."

The episode refers to it as "*a Festivus for the rest of us*", referencing its non-commercial aspect. The English word *festive* derives from Latin "festivus", which in turn derives from *festus* "joyous; holiday, feast day".

Happy Festivus!

(Xmas has been used for hundreds of years in religious writing, where the X represents a Greek chi, the first letter of Χριστος, *Christ.*)

Comment: I like that a lot... I think I'll go with it this year.  :-)

Comment: I'm dreaming of a white Festivus!